# _NSDate length unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I'm trying to convert a NSString to a NSDate

The NSString destructString is 2015-01-04 08:36:42 +0000

**I know the problem starts at the place that I commented below but I can't seem to find what the problem is.**

The program stops at that point and gives the error in the title.

The point of the code is to compare two dates to see which one is older.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];


NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc]init];



[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
    for(PFObject* object in [self objects]){
        NSLog(@"OBJECT:  %@", object);
        PAWPost *post = [[PAWPost alloc] initWithPFObject:object];
        NSLog(@"post: %@", post);
        NSLog(@"today: %@", today);

        NSString *destructString = [post.object objectForKey:selfDestructDateKey];
            NSLog(@"destruct string: %@", destructString);

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zz"];

        //SOURCE OF PROBLEM BEGINS HERE
        NSDate *destructDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:destructString];

        NSLog(@"destruct date: %@", destructDate);

        if([destructDate compare:today] == NSOrderedDescending){
            [object deleteEventually];
            NSLog(@"DESCENDING");
        }

        else
            NSLog(@"NOT DESCENDING");

    }

    }else {

        NSLog(@"Error in findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock for destruct purposes");
    }
}];
```

**Also I know there's another post on this subject however I have tried that fix (which was redoing the formatting) but it did not solve the issue. Thanks in advance!**

Comment: looks like `[post.object objectForKey:selfDestructDateKey]` already returns you `NSDate` object ))

Comment: I feel dumb now but thanks it works! :)

Comment: please check my answer that can prove my guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if type of objects can vary you should add type check as I added to your code

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
    for(PFObject* object in [self objects]){
        NSLog(@"OBJECT:  %@", object);
        PAWPost *post = [[PAWPost alloc] initWithPFObject:object];
        NSLog(@"post: %@", post);
        NSLog(@"today: %@", today);

        id destructString = [post.object objectForKey:selfDestructDateKey];
            NSLog(@"destruct string: %@", destructString);
     if ([destructString isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) { // already date 
           NSDate * destructDate = (NSDate *)destructString;
     } else { // parse string  
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zz"];

        //SOURCE OF PROBLEM BEGINS HERE
        NSDate *destructDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:destructString];

        NSLog(@"destruct date: %@", destructDate);

        if([destructDate compare:today] == NSOrderedDescending){
            [object deleteEventually];
            NSLog(@"DESCENDING");
        }

        else
            NSLog(@"NOT DESCENDING");
}
    }

    }else {

        NSLog(@"Error in findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock for destruct purposes");
    }
}];
```